# nmcli edit connection not avaiable

Tags: ssh, network-manager, nmcli

Ubuntu version: 14.04

Network manager **enabled**.

I am using SSH connection and I would like to edit a connection through `nmcli connection edit`, but it just no available.

I checked all available commands and it just doesn't display it:

```
$ sudo nmcli connection help

Usage: nmcli connection { COMMAND | help }
  COMMAND := { list | status | up | down | delete }

  list [id <id> | uuid <id>]
  status [id <id> | uuid <id> | path <path>]
  up id <id> | uuid <id> [iface <iface>] [ap <BSSID>] [--nowait] [--timeout <timeout>]
  down id <id> | uuid <id>
  delete id <id> | uuid <id>
```

Why? What can I do to overcome it?

**[Edit 1]** Reference link: https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/1.2/nmcli.html

**[Edit 2]**

```
$ dpkg -s network-manager | grep 'Version'
Version: 0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.3
```

**[Edit 3]** Main goal: Using NetworkManager, set a static IP to a specific connection.

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? As you have seen, `nmcli connection` (at least, your version of it) doesn't have an `edit` action. If you can enable X forwarding, you may be able to use `nm-connection-editor` instead. Or you may be able to do what you want by editing the connection file directly.

Comment: X forwading is not working. Perhaps I could edit the connection file. How can I do it? Is there a template to write this file?

Comment: You still haven't told us what you are trying to do.

Comment: @steeldriver Use static IP to a connection.

Comment: Well, the structure of the `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<id>` files is described in the nm-settings manual page `man nm-settings`